# maven make same project 32 and 64 build twice but end up with same jar versioned file and only once updated POM version

Tags: maven

I am new to maven. I need to build my java project using underlying libraries that are 32 and 64 bit dependent. I have 2 Maven profiles 32bit and 64bit - these get appended to underlying libraries and also appended to the final jar filename so I end up with file name myfile_32-x.y.jar or myfile_64-x.y.jar. My problem is - every time I run maven build and specify either 32 or 64 bit profile I use release:prepare release:perform. After build is complete my jar file version gets incremented and POM file gets updated either after 32bit build or 64 bit build. I want to somehow specify an instruction not to update POM after 32 bit build and only update POM after 64 bit build is finished. My goal to run both builds and produce same jar file version.

Comment: Can you tell what kind of libraries those are and which Java version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a multi-module project with three modules:

- one with the common code
- one for the 32-bit version
- one for the 64-bit version

The two latter ones use the common code as dependency. Then you can build all of them with the same version number.